# Is this a correct summary of Cocoa reference counting?

Tags: cocoa, reference-counting, summary

Here's my understanding of it:

Object are **only** retained (reference counter is incremented):

1. when `init` from `NSObject` is called.
2. when `retain` is called.

Objects are **only** released (reference counter is decremented):

1. when `release` is called.
2. when an autorelease pool containing the object is drained

And to clarify, autorelease does **not** retain, but just places the object into the top most pool on the autorelease pool stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

`init` does not retain, and there are various methods you didn’t mention which do. There is a simple (and also correct) summary in [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994).

(There are two exceptions that I’m aware of: the `NSPropertyListSerialization` methods which provide a retained error string by reference.)

Comment: The NSPropertyListSerialization docs explicitly tell you that the method in question is breaking the rules, too.

Comment: Another good summary is in Cocoa Core Competencies: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html